# How to select a particular column in a dataframe among two columns based on the column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe

```
        _id     _score      ensembl   ensembl.gene  notfound
query                   
Dnmt3a  1788    89.405594   NaN      ENSG00000119772     NaN
SUMO1   7341    85.157100   NaN      ENSG00000116030    NaN
GADD45a 1647    86.867760   NaN      ENSG00000116717    NaN
Rad17   5884    85.377050   [{u'gene': u'ENSG00000155093'}, {u'gene': u'ENSG00000282185'}]  NaN NaN
DRS     NaN     NaN         NaN       NaN               True
```

On the basis of the values of 'ensembl', 'ensembl.gene' and 'notfound', how to find out the ensemble id for a particular instance. 
The output should be based on three conditions

1. If both the value of 'ensembl' and 'ensembl.gene' is 'NaN', then output is "Not found". e.g. fifth row.
2. If the value of 'ensembl' is 'NaN', then just print the value of 'ensembl.gene' e.g. first, second and third row.
3. If the value of 'ensembl.gene' is 'NaN', then print first part of the value of 'ensembl' e.g. in fourth row the value of 'ensembl.gene' is 'NaN', hence the output is the first part of 'ensembl' value i.e. ENSG00000155093.

The output should be

```
    Ensemble_ID
query                   
Dnmt3a  ENSG00000119772
SUMO1   ENSG00000116030
GADD45a ENSG00000116717
Rad17   ENSG00000155093
DRS     Not_found
```

Comment: You should improve the formatting in your df, it seems you have a dict within ensembl.

Comment: Rephrased the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you need:

```
import numpy as np

def make_id(row): 
    if row['ensembl'] is np.nan and row['ensembl.gene'] is np.nan:  # 1) If both the value of 'ensembl' and 'ensembl.gene' is 'NaN', then output is "Not found".
        return 'Not Found'
    elif row['ensembl'] is np.nan:                                  # 2) If the value of 'ensembl' is 'NaN', then just print the value of 'ensembl.gene'
        return row['ensembl.gene']
    else:                                                           # 3) (otherwise) If the value of 'ensembl.gene' is 'NaN', then print first part of the value of 'ensembl' 
        return row['ensembl'][0]['gene']



df = pd.DataFrame({'ensembl': [np.nan,[{u'gene': u'ENSG00000155093'}],np.nan], 'ensembl.gene':[1,4,5]})
df['id'] = df.apply(lambda row: make_id(row), axis=1)
print(df)  

                         ensembl  ensembl.gene               id
0                           None             1                1
1  [{'gene': 'ENSG00000155093'}]             4  ENSG00000155093
2                           None             5                5
```

In this way the ids of each row of your df are generated and saved in the corresponding `'id'` column.

> **Note:** If the missing value is not represented by np.nan, replace np.nan with another placeholder 'nan' inside the algorithm

Comment: Why? Can you try posting the code to create the df of your example? So I can check too

Comment: In the algorithm I had confused 'ensembl.gene' with 'ensemble.gene'. I corrected. Was that the problem?

Comment: I checked your code on github. As I told you, you had to check if the data type 'NaN', and if so replace it with the correct one. In your case the 'NaN' values ​​are of float type, so I had to use numpy which provides the placeholder np.nan for the missing float numbers. I updated the answer, now you find the correct code version :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Massifox

Comment: Great! Can you mark my answer as the best answer? Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this code solved your problem:

```
searched_id = df.loc[df['ensembl']=='ENSG00000119772'].index[0]
```

You can generalize the code in a simple way as follows:

```
def get_index(df, pred)
    return df.loc[pred].index
```

In this way the results are filtered according to the predicate, and the corresponding index list is returned.
An example of use is the following:

```
pred = (df['ensemble']=='val1') & (df['ensembl.gene']=='val2') & (df['notfound']=='val3')
searched_id = get_index(df, pred)
```

> If I haven't answered your question, try to rephrase the question because it's really unclear

Comment: Thanks @Massifox. I rephrase and described elaborately my question.

Answer (score 1):

First create a copy of the column "ensemble.gene". Then apply the "where" method and some regex. Finally use "fillna".

```
df["Ensemble_ID"]=df["ensembl.gene"]
df["Ensemble_ID"]=df["Ensemble_ID"].where(df["ensembl"].isna(),df["ensembl"].str.extract(r"u'(ENSG\d+)",expand=False))
df["Ensemble_ID"].fillna("Not_found",inplace=True)

df["Ensemble_ID"]                                                                                                   
query
Dnmt3a     ENSG00000119772
SUMO1      ENSG00000116030
GADD45a    ENSG00000116717
Rad17      ENSG00000155093
DRS              Not_found
Name: Ensemble_ID, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to find the value of `"_id"` that correspond to known values of `'ensembl', 'ensembl.gene'` and `'notfound'`. 
Here how to do it with a toy dataframe (easily extendable to your case).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0,1,2,3],
                   'col_1':[11,12,13,14],
                   'col_2':[110,120,130,140],
                   'col_3':[1100,1200,1300,1400]})
condition = np.logical_and(
    np.logical_and(df['col_1']==13,
                   df['col_2']==130),df['col_3']==1300)
print (f'the index(es) corresponding to the values of the columns is:
       {df["id"][condition].values}')
# output
the index corresponding to the values of the columns is: [2]
```